# Javascript parse id from referrer

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the `document.referrer` property to get the following URLs:

```
http://www.site.ru/profile/521590819123/friends
http://www.site.ru/profile/521590819123
http://www.site.ru/profile/521590819123/else
```

I need to get the ID (for instance, 521590819123 as seen above) from this string into a variable. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ref = document.referrer;
var url = 'http://site.com/?id=';
if( ref.indexOf('profile') >= 0 ) 
{
  ref = ref.substr(ref.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  window.top.location.href = (url+ref);
}
else
 {
 window.top.location.href = (url + '22');
 }
</script>
```

But this only works if the referrer string is in the format `http://www.site.ru/profile/521590819123`. The other examples above with `/friends` or `/else` on the end won't work. Can someone help me fix the code to take care of these instances?

Comment: It's worth noting that the referrer string isn't always reliable. There are many browser extensions that let you change or block it.

Comment: Any answers to this will be incomplete - you haven't given us enough information.  Will the referer always be the same host?  Will the path always start with "profile", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest with a regex:

```
var m, id;
m = /profile\/(\d+)/.exec(document.referrer);
if (m) {
    id = m[1];
}
```

That regex says "Find the first location where the text `profile/` is followed by digits and put the digits in a capture group." Then the code checks that there was a match (in case the string doesn't have it at all) and, if so, takes the value from the first capture group (which is at index 1; index 0 is the whole matching string). Modify as necessary (for instance, to only match if the string is `www.site.ru/profile/` rather than just `profile/`, etc.).